# Humanae pantone colors to RGB conversion

Tags: color-spaces, rgb

How to find the RGB color codes for the humanae project-[humanae link](http://humanae.tumblr.com/). It uses pantone colors, but the codes given in the website at humanae couldnt be found on pantone color finder at [pantone-color finder](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder)

Comment: Try to find another usage of these codes and you probably won't.

Comment: https://www.pantone.com/color-finder?q=%23FFC997 - check this out, there are no similar numbers for an example colour.

Comment: You may also use background of each image as a colour picker source, this will give you numbers in the colour space which you need (RGB is not colour space).

Comment: Assuming that Pantone site uses sRGB for their queries I could not find 77-9 C at all using [source image](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder?q=%23EADBD5).

Comment: Reading the ["about" page](http://humanae.tumblr.com/About) for the project, one could get the impression that the imitation of a Pantone chart is more about artistic statement than actual color theory.

Comment: Have you contacted the page author? And why not download the images and sample the background in an image editor? You'd need to know the color space but presumably that is embedded and/or sRGB.

Comment: I have downloaded a few samples and I am going to sample it using opencv/gimp. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check a special Pantone booklet: https://www.pantone.com/skintone-guide

To get the RGB values of that page you can grab a color picker and measure it. For example on windows, this is a useful tool: http://www.color-picker.de/en

Of course we are relying that the images have the proper color profile embedded.

You could also open them in Photowhatever and take a reading there.

Comment: Do I need to buy the skintone-guide or is there a free pdf from where I could see the RGB values